# jQuery to change div content when click span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So This is the html I wrote:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="language.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="eng"> Change this English sentence </div>
   <span id="frn" style="text-decoration:underline">French</span>
</body>
```

Meanwhile, the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frn").on('click', function(){
        $(".eng").html("modifier cette phrase en anglais");
    });
});
```

I use Microsoft Expression Web 4.0.1460.0 to generate this codes.
So, what I want to do is change the text on a div when user click on span. In this case, change a defined text from english to french when someone click on span with text French and ID #frn.

However, when I preview this on Google Chrome. It didn't work. By clicking the span, nothing happened.
Please kindly help me on this.

Comment: it would seem that you are not linking the jQuery library in your page before calling the function

Comment: that's right, thank you very much!

Comment: welcome - its also better if you put all js code at the end of the page for speed in page loading. just a thought - happy coding :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI check the updated code you havent include the jquery library , this works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frn").on('click', function(){
        $(".eng").html("modifier cette phrase en anglais");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>



  <div class="eng"> Change this English sentence </div>
   <span id="frn" style="text-decoration:underline">French</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that! Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @brandeluke Hi, please mark this answer as correct answer if it helped you. Look for doing this in the future.. Thanks and cheers. ;)

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine in this JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5g3decLd/1/

Also, I would suggest to change html() to text()

```
$(".eng").text("modifier cette phrase en anglais");
```